# How to stop Telescope.nvim from changing directories when a file is opened

Tags: neovim, telescope.nvim

I don't like this behavior. I want to always anchor myself in the root folder of my project however plugins like Telescope (or FZF) keep changing the folder on me.

How can I stop this? thanks

Comment: Have you found a fix for this issue already?

Comment: Nope! I just stopped using neovim for the moment

Comment: I had a similar problem which persisted even with all plugins disabled. Updating neovim from d0ced2a12 (July 2022) to 629169462 (August 2022) fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I installed [airblade/vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter) and it solved the issue for me.